# @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit4

I will try to test one of methods in my endpoint (spring 3.1, junit 4.11) Here are my codes:
applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns: p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     
http://www.springframework.org/schem...ng-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schem...-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schem...ontext-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schem...ring-cache.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="app.controller, app.samples" />
<context:annotation-config/>
<annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

and test class:

```
package app.tests;
import app.samples.TableEndpoint;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autow ired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfigurat ion;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUni t4ClassRunner;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TableTest {

public TableTest() {
}
@Autowired
TableEndpoint tableEndpoint;
@Test
public void testTableEndpoint(){
String result = tableEndpoint.getDane().get(0);
String expResult = "Learn python in 7 days";
if(!result.equals(expResult)){
fail("not equals");
}
assertTrue(result.equals(expResult));
}
}
```

If I run test I have got :

```
org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManage r retrieveTestExecutionListeners<br>
INFO: @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [class app.tests.TableTest]: using defaults.
```

I searched about it but didn't find some informations. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You miss the TestExecutionListeners. Add this annotation to your class

```
@TestExecutionListeners( { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class })
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TableTest {
...
}
```